# Visual Studio 2015 with BizTalk Server 2016 cannot load Microsoft.BizTalk.CrossReferencingFunctoids.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2015, biztalk, biztalk-2016

The workaround to resolve the error described below was to effectively remove the features provided by seven standard BizTalk Server 2016 database functoids. The desire is to be able to not have to do so.

When building a project we get this error:

[image: The "MapperCompiler" task failed unexpectedly. ...]

> The "MapperCompiler" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.ApplicationException: Unable to load wrapper:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016\Developer Tools\Mapper Extensions\Microsoft.BizTalk.CrossReferencingFunctoids.dll. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Mapper Compiler: Unable to load assembly from file or partial name C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016\Developer Tools\Mapper Extensions\Microsoft.BizTalk.CrossReferencingFunctoids.dll
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Mapper.OM.FunctoidManager.AddWrapper(String reference)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Mapper.OM.FunctoidManager.LoadWrappers(String[] references)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.BizTalkProject.Compiler.MapCompiler.Compile(BizTalkBuildSnapshot buildSnapshot, IEnumerable`1 mapFilesToCompile, IEnumerable`1 schemaFiles, List`1& generatedCodeFiles, List`1& xsltFiles)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.BizTalkProject.BuildTasks.MapperCompiler.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()        {my project name}

Meanwhile, when attempting to open an existing map or create a new map, we get this error:

[image: Microsoft BizTalk Mapper - Unable to load wrapper:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016\Developer Tools\Mapper Extensions\Microsoft.BizTalk.CrossReferencingFunctoids.dll.]

Picture of the assembly's location (shows its size and the date of its publication by MS):

[image: Microsoft.BizTalk.CrossReferencingFunctoids.dll published 9/30/2016 9:43 PM, size 38KB]

This assembly has been a stock component of BizTalk Server mapping database functoids since at least version 2006 R2. The functoids are described in the MS docs for BTS:

[image: MS docs description of Database Functoids]

The functoids appear like this on the map design surface in Visual Studio:

[image: How the functoids appear in VS 2015]

These BizTalkMgmtDb tables are the targets of the cross-referencing functoids:

[image: BizTalkMgmtDb tables used by the cross-referencing functoids]

FYI [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4365c2f-15bd-4edd-90c5-1aea690145a4/mapper-build-failed?forum=biztalkgeneral) is the oldest post I have been able to find for this exact symptom. No solution to this post was published:

[image: picture of BTS 2006 R2 occurrence of identical symptom]

**Here was our ghastly workaround: *delete Microsoft.BizTalk.CrossReferencingFunctoids.dll***

The effects of deleting the assembly from its location at...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016\Developer Tools\Mapper Extensions
```

...are twofold:

- The errors (when building a project that has maps and when attempting to create a new map or display an existing map) go away.
- The usefulness of the cross referencing functoids is unavailable. These seven functoids still appear on the mapping design surface's toolbox, but if you attempt to use one you get this message (the functoids still appear in the toolbox - presumably because the assembly is still in the GAC):

[image: picture shows the functoids in the toolbox but not available to the mapper]

NOTE: FYI, I can't get any of these symptoms on my Windows 10 PC, even after taking pains to configure it to match the server environment by these steps:

- Installed BTS 2016 Cumulative Update 5
- Installed the same .NET Framework 4.7.2 (aka 4.7.03062) as is used on the server

The problem's server environment:

- BizTalk Server 2016 including Cumulative Update 5
- BizTalk installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter (x64) - specifically  version 6.3.9600 Build 9600. The server is up-to-date with patches
- Visual Studio 2015 (the version required to work with BTS 2016)
- SQL Server 2016 SP2 (build 1.3.0.5161.0) database is on a separate computer

Comment: What if you remove it from the GAC. Keep it in the Mapper Extensions and restart and refresh the toolbox?

Comment: I did try what you suggested, r3verse. The result was the same as shown in the last image of the post. We have also repaired BizTalk; and I have even deleted the assembly's folder structure from the GAC before performing the repair to prove the new copy after the repair was created by the repair. Also, replace both copies of the assembly (one in Program Files (x86)\... and one in the GAC) with the actual file on my Windows 10 PC which has no problems with this assembly. Each time I restarted the server after any changes I made in the GAC.

Comment: Make sure you try with a new BizTalk project and not an existing one. Also verify you're using  .NET Framework 4.6 for the project target. 

Also, check the 'Choose Toolbox Items' -> 'BizTalk Mapper Functoids' window and see if the directory for the functoid looks good.

If it's still not working at that point, try removing some Windows updates related to .Net framework. Start with removing the framework versions you don't really need (like .NET Framework 4.7.2). Lately they had some issues related to this, see this [advisory](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/74).

Comment: Yes r3verse, I have performed those drills (I was overkilling the post with pictures but I did have a picture demonstrating the Choose Toolbox Items routine). The reason .NET is at 4.7.2 is the management wanted this server set all the way to current. I have created brand-new BTS projects targeted at 4.6, tried x86 even. But this has been through so many iterations I will try that again. Also, we have been through the July 2018 rollup problem, and this server does have the newer August rollup that includes the fixes to the July rollup.

Comment: Do a Repair of the BizTalk installation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; yes, we did that too (see Sep 6 at 15:20 comment). We have also repaired Visual Studio 2015 in case there was anything wrong there.

Comment: Moderator, please leave this question open. I monitor it every day in hopes that another of the BTS heavyweights will notice it.

Answer (score 0):

You stated you are running Windows Server 2012, this version is NOT supported for BizTalk 2016. Only Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2016 are currently supported.

Comment: You're a good reader. I updated the post with the fact that the OS is indeed Windows Server 2012 R2.